# Mock all static void methods of a class

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock, powermock

I am using Mockito along with PowerMock to mock the static methods of a class. I have provided an example below:

```
PowerMock.mockStatic(SampleClass.class);
SampleClass.doNothing();
EasyMock.expectLastCall().once();
```

This code mocks the doNothing() methods for once. However, I have other static void methods in the same class. If any attempt is made to call them then, an exception is thrown.

I have two questions:

1. Do I need to mock all the static methods in the class by copying line 2 and 3 for each method? Is there any other simpler way to mock all the methods in a line or two?
2. If my method is a static void method and I want to provide another implementation when the method is called (e.g. my method closes PreparedStatement, ResultSet and Connection and I want to mock it by closing only PreparedStatement and ResultSet) then, is it possible?

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are calling other static methods then you have to set expectation for those method as well (step 2 and 3 in your example).
2. Can you please provide examples of your code.  I am not clear about what you are trying to do.